# Copy range until empty row and paste into new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA macro for Excel 2013. It's purpose is to merge two worksheets into a combined worksheet. (I tried to find a built in feature to do this but was unable to find what I needed).

What the macro needs to do is this:

1. Activate "Sheet3" and clear all rows starting with row 3 and down
2. Go into "Sheet1" and copy all rows starting with (A3:P3) and copy down until, and not including, the first row with null in the A column.
3. Go into "Sheet3" and paste those rows starting at A3.
4. Go into "Sheet2" and copy all rows starting with (A3:P3) and copy down until, and not including, the first row with null in the A column.
5. Go into "Sheet3" and past those rows starting at the first empty cell in column A.

I'm a novice at VBA but I've managed to find the following code and I'm trying to make it work to accomplish the above requirements.

```
Sub CreateCombinedSheet()
  lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row
  ActiveSheet.Range("A3", ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 12)).Copy
End Sub
```

I'm trying to write parts of it and test it as I go but I'm already getting a 1004 error with this:

`Application-defined or object-defined error`

Any thoughts on how I should work this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Activate "Sheet3" and clear all rows starting with row 3 and down

You do not need to activate a sheet to clear the rows. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) You can directly say

```
Sheets("BlahBlah").Rows("3:200").ClearContents
```

I have hardcoded `200` as an example. To find the end of rows, see the below point.

> Go into "Sheet1" and copy all rows starting with (A3:P3) and copy down until, and not including, the first row with null in the A column.

Same for this. You do not need to go to that sheet. You need to first find the last row. I see that you are hardcoing the rows in your code. You don't need to do that. xl2007+ now has 1048576 rows. Use `.Rows.Count` Please see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

> Go into "Sheet3" and paste those rows starting at A3.

To paste, you again don't need to go to that sheet. You can directly say

```
rng.Copy Sheet("BlahBlah").Rows(3)
```

Your point 4 and 5 are just variations of the above. I am sure you can now take it from here :). In case you still face any difficulty, simply post back.